# How to make a method call wait for an animation to finish

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I want to make a notification window with animated text. A notification would be sent by a button click and the animation would start playing. My problem is that when I click the button again before the previous animation is done, two animations get executed at once. How do I make each method call of "sendMessage()" wait for the other to finish? If it has any significance there are multiple nodes that call the sendMessage() method in my program unlike in my MRE, so I want some kind of Queue with messages. Here is my MRE:

```
public class AnimationTest extends Application {

  private final Label messageLabel = new Label();

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 320, 240);
    vBox.getChildren().add(messageLabel);
    Button button = new Button();
    button.setOnAction(event -> sendMessage("Some animated text."));
    vBox.getChildren().add(button);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }

  private void sendMessage(String message) {
    final IntegerProperty i = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(
        Duration.millis(40),
        event -> {
          if (i.get() > message.length()) {
            timeline.stop();
          } else {
            messageLabel.setText(message.substring(0, i.get()));
            i.set(i.get() + 1);
          }
        });
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the specific example you posted, the easiest approach is to disable the button immediately prior to starting the animation, and enable it again when the animation stops. Here is one way to do this:

```
public class AnimationTest extends Application {

    private final Label messageLabel = new Label();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 320, 240);
        vBox.getChildren().add(messageLabel);
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            Animation animation = sendMessage("Some animated text.");
            button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.equal(animation.statusProperty(), Animation.Status.RUNNING));
        });
        vBox.getChildren().add(button);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private Animation sendMessage(String message) {
        final IntegerProperty i = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(
                Duration.millis(40),
                event -> {
                    if (i.get() > message.length()) {
                        timeline.stop();
                    } else {
                        messageLabel.setText(message.substring(0, i.get()));
                        i.set(i.get() + 1);
                    }
                });
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
        return timeline ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

If you want to allow these messages to accumulate in a queue, and a new animation to start when the old one finishes, you need to keep a queue of the messages and a reference to a current animation that's running (if there is one). You can poll the queue from an `AnimationTimer` and start a new animation when a new message appears, if there is no current animation running.

I'd recommend thinking about whether this is the approach you want to take; there's no guarantee here that your messages will not appear more quickly than they can be animated, in which case the queue will grow indefinitely. However, this is an implementation if you can otherwise assure that this is not the case:

```
public class AnimationTest extends Application {

    private final Label messageLabel = new Label();
    
    private final Queue<String> messages = new LinkedList<>();
    private Animation currentAnimation = null ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 320, 240);
        vBox.getChildren().add(messageLabel);
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setOnAction(event -> messages.add("Some animated text."));

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long l) {
                if (currentAnimation == null || currentAnimation.getStatus() == Animation.Status.STOPPED) {
                    String message = messages.poll();
                    if (message != null) {
                        currentAnimation = sendMessage(message);
                        currentAnimation.play();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
        vBox.getChildren().add(button);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private Animation sendMessage(String message) {
        final IntegerProperty i = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(
                Duration.millis(40),
                event -> {
                    if (i.get() > message.length()) {
                        timeline.stop();
                    } else {
                        messageLabel.setText(message.substring(0, i.get()));
                        i.set(i.get() + 1);
                    }
                });
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        return timeline ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Note there are no threading considerations here. The `handle()` method is invoked on the FX Application Thread, so the only requirement is that the messages are placed in the queue on the same thread. This happens in this example because the button's event handler is invoked on that thread. If your messages are coming from a background thread, you should ensure they are added to the queue on the FX Application Thread, either by using `Platform.runLater(...)` or (preferably) by using the JavaFX Concurrency API (i.e. by retrieving the messages in a `Task` or `Service` and adding them to the queue in an `onSucceeded` handler).

Answer (score -2):

1. Set a boolean (best do it atomic, because multithreading and stuff...) at animation start & end.
2. Disable the Button when boolean is in animation phase.

Comment: *”because multithreading”*. What multithreading? Everything here is running on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: OK, fair point. Let me reprahse this to: "Eventdriven". Point is, there are probably other events that could trigger this animation? Therefore you want to be sure, that the boolean is definitly well communicated, without any race conditions.

Comment: There are no other threads. How can there be race conditions?

Comment: This is just a code snippet. I have no idea how your application looks like. But if you animate something, it would be a standard design aproach to do this animation in a seperate thread.

Comment: It’s not my code. *”It would be a standard design approach to do this animation in a separate thread.”*. This is completely incorrect. The JavaFX Animation API does not create any separate threads.

Comment: Yes this is true simple apps, but again. I have no idea how your code looks like. If it gets more complex with multiple animations you would do it slightly different, because if you animate 1000 frames, your appliction does exactly nothing anymore. Have a look at good old [Jenkov](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/javafx/concurrency.html).

Comment: Why do you keep referring to “my code”? The OP has posted a perfectly good [mre] which is complete (except for imports) and demonstrates the problem. Your answer doesn’t solve it and is full of misinformation.

Comment: Ah sorry, I just relized now you're not the one how asked the Question.
Why is the answer not solving the problem? If you disable the button, it can't be triggered a second animation?

Comment: What is the purpose of this boolean? Why not just disable the button when the animation starts and enable it when it ends? And why do you still refer to multithreading when this is all single-threaded?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245786/discussion-between-simplejack-and-james-d).

Comment: again, because i dont't know the complete application. maybe it was premature assumption, it would be a more complex application. next time i will strictly refere to the given example.